# How to get tab label text using ng-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Im looking for some solution to get tab label text on li ng-click. i'm using radio button for multiple options. suppose i click on local tab button and then selected poin to point radio button. im getting radio button value but i need category name also (local & outstation).

```
<ul class="tabs">
 <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tabs-1">LOCAL</li>
 <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tabs-2">OUTSTATION</li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content current">
                                    <div class="tab-elements">
                                        <div class="checkboxes-demo">
                                            <div class="fac fac-radio fac-default"><span></span>
                                                <input id="box1-fac-radio" type="radio" name="radioPlatFormName" ng-change="radioPlatForm('Point to Point')" value="Point to Point" ng-model="selectCar.platform">
                                                <label for="box1-fac-radio">Point to Point</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="fac fac-radio fac-default"><span></span>
                                                <input id="box2-fac-radio" type="radio" name="radioPlatFormName" ng-change="radioPlatForm('Hourly')" value="Hourly" ng-model="selectCar.platform">
                                                <label for="box2-fac-radio">Hourly</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-elements">
                                        <div class="checkboxes-demo">
                                            <div class="fac fac-radio fac-default"><span></span>
                                                <input id="box3-fac-radio" type="radio" name="radioPlatFormName" ng-change="radioPlatForm('One Way')" value="One Way" ng-model="selectCar.platform">
                                                <label for="box3-fac-radio">One Way</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="fac fac-radio fac-default"><span></span>
                                                <input id="box4-fac-radio" type="radio" name="radioPlatFormName" ng-change="radioPlatForm('Round Trip')" value="Round Trip" ng-model="selectCar.platform">
                                                <label for="box4-fac-radio">Round Trip</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Here is my app code for getting radio button value

```
    var appModule = angular.module('cormobApp', []);
appModule.controller('selectCarCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.radioPlatForm = function(platformChange) {
                $scope.platformSelected = platformChange;
            }
```

Comment: can you share jsfiddle sample link?

Comment: Did you understand what i want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span class="third-text-right" ng-if="selectCar.platform == 'Hourly' || selectCar.platform == 'Point to Point'">Local</span>
 <span class="third-text-right" ng-if="selectCar.platform == 'One Way' || selectCar.platform == 'Round Trip'">Outstation</span>
```

I used two spans to show which tab is selected when clicking any sub option it will compare which radio button value match with condition it will show that span.

Thanks for prompt response guys. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

Inside your HTML

```
<li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tabs-1" ng-click="TabName('Local')">LOCAL</li>
 <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tabs-2" ng-click="TabName('Outstation')">OUTSTATION</li>
```

Inside your Controller

```
  $scope.TabName= function(name) {
           alert(name);// You can get selected tab name here
     }
```

Comment: its not working. i want this name text should appear in html span

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way

on js

```
$scope.local = "LOCAL"
$scope.outstation = "OUTSTATION"

$scope.localfunction = function (local) {
$scope.platformSelected = local;
}

$scope.outstationfunction = function (outstation) {
$scope.platformSelected = outstation;
}
```

on html

```
 <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tabs-1" ng-click="localfunction('local')">{{ local }}</li>
 <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tabs-2" ng-click="outstationfunction('outstation')>{{ outstation }}</li>
```

Comment: How do i get which one is selected ?

Comment: you can set a default on since tabbing starts at left you can set $scope.local first the value